# what is the difference between linear transformation and affine transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra, discrete-mathematics, transformation

Recently, I am struglling with the difference between linear transformation and affine transformation. Are they the same ? 
I found an interesting question on the difference between the functions. But still, not very clear.

[What is the difference between linear and affine function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/275310/what-is-the-difference-between-linear-and-affine-function)
http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AffineTransformation.html

Comment: Every linear transformation $f$ is an affine transformation such that $f(0)=0$.

Comment: @Surb, Can we discuss based on set ?

Comment: what do you mean by "based on set"?

Answer (score 21):

A linear transformation is any transformation $f: U\to V$ between vector spaces over $\mathbb F$ for which

- $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$
- $f(\alpha x) = \alpha f(x)$

for all $x,y\in U$ and all $\alpha\in\mathbb F$.

An affine transformation is any transformation $f:U\to V$ for which, if $\sum_i\lambda_i = 1$, $$f(\sum_i \lambda_i x_i) = \sum_i \lambda_i f(x_i)$$
for all sets of vectors $x_i\in U$.

In effect, what these two definitions mean is:

1. All linear transformations are affine transformations.
2. Not all affine transformations are linear transformations.
3. It can be shown that any affine transformation $A:U\to V$ can be written as $A(x) = L(x) + v_0$, where $v_0$ is some vector from $V$ and $L:U\to V$ is a linear transformation.

Take an example where $U=V=\mathbb R^2$. Then $$f:(x,y) \mapsto(-2x+y, 3x+8y)$$ is a linear transformation, since

$$f((x_1,y_1)+(x_2, y_2)) = (-2(x_1+x_2) + y_1+y_2, 3(x_1+x_2) + 8(y_1+y_2)) = \\ 
= (-2x_1 + y_1, 3x_1 + 8y_1) + (-2x_2 + y_2, 3x_2 + 8y_2) = f((x_1,y_1)+f((x_2, y_2))$$

However, $$g:(x,y)\mapsto (-2x+y+5, 3x+8y-2)$$
is *not* a linear transformation(you can immediatelly see this since $g((0,0)) \neq (0,0)$, while linear transformation always map $0$ to $0$).

Both $g$ and $f$ are (you can check) affine transformation.

Comment: Maybe $\sum_{i}\lambda_i = 1$.

Comment: @guanglei You are correct. Thank you.

Comment: @5xum I think this is false $$f(\sum_i \lambda_i x_i) = \sum_i \lambda_i x_i$$

Comment: it should be $$f(\sum_i \lambda_i x_i) = \sum_i \lambda_i f(x_i)$$

Comment: Interpretation of the formula is that affine transformation preserves mass centres of sets (i.e., barycenters). You can think of $\lambda_i$ as weights and $x_i$ as a set of objects. The mass centre of the set ${x_i}_{i=1}^n$ is $\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i x_i$. Then the main formula boils down to **mass centre of the set is mapped to the mass centre of the map of the set**

Answer (score 2):

Let $V,W$ be some $\Bbb K$ vector space.

- $f:V \to W$ is linear if for every $\alpha,\mu\in \Bbb K$ and $v_1,v_2\in V$ we have $f(\alpha v_1+\mu v_2) = \alpha f(v_1)+\mu f(v_2)$.
- $g:V\to W$ is affine if there exists $b\in V$ such that $\tilde g:V\to W:v \mapsto g(v)-b$ is linear.

Comment: In particular every linear transformation is affine (choose $b=0$) but the reverse is not true.

Comment: Thanks @Surb. Now I got it. What I mean is as follows:

Answer (score 2):

An alternative point of view is that, given any vector space $V$, we extend it by one dimension by including a new nonzero vector $o$ and also all linear combinations of it and the existing vectors. Call this new vector space, an **affine space** and denote it $a(V,o)$. Call the elements of $V+o$ **points** of the affine space and any nonzero vector is a scalar multiple of some point which we call a **weighted point** where the scalar is the **weight** of the point. Now if a linear map between two affine spaces $f: a(V_1,o_1) \to a(V_2,o_2)$ satisfies $f(V_1)\subset V_2$ and $f(o_1) = v_2 + o_2$ where $v_2\in V_2$, then we call it an **affine map**. That is, we require this because we want points to map to points. You can check that composition of affine maps is affine and $f(v_1 + o_1) = (f(v_1) + v_2) + o_2$. This is like the usual $y=mx+b$. Think of the vector $o$ as a bookkeeping device to keep track of an origin. That is, in a vector space there is a unique zero vector, but in an affine space, all points can be regarded effectively as an origin. If $f(o_1) = o_2$ then $v_2=0$ and $f$ is just a linear map just like $y=mx$. So all affine maps are linear but not vice versa.