# New Temperature Scale

Tags: algebra-precalculus

A new temperature scale is to be sued where freezing and boiling temperature of water is at -100 deg N and 100 deg N respectively. Calculate Absolute Zero in Degree N

Answer is -992.6 Degree N

Absolute Zero in C = 273.15 C

I use Ratio and Proportion:

Total Scale in N = 100 - - 100 = 200

Total Scale in C = 100 - 0 = 100

( Current Temp ) / (Overall Scale) = x/200 = 273.15/100

x = 546.3 N

What am I doing wrong? Any Hint? Am I not supposed to use Ratio and Proportion?

Comment: I can't see how to get the given answer of -992.6 N, but Absolute Zero in C is -273.15 C, not +273.15 C.

Comment: Curious $4*(-273.15) +100 = - 992.6$

Comment: I once knew a man who froze himself to absolute zero. He was $0K$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We would assume that the new scale is an [affine transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformation) of others (this is not explicitly stated, which is problematic because without this assumption there is no way to solve the problem).

Therefore it's simple: come up with an [affine function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/275310/what-is-the-difference-between-linear-and-affine-function) which relates Celsius to the new system:

$$
f(x) = ax + b
$$

They give you two points.  The freezing point is $-100$ and the boiling point is $+100$.  Since we know that this corresponds to $0^\circ\ C$ and $100^\circ\ C$ this gives:

$$
f(0) = b = -100 \\
f(100) = 100a + b = 100 \rightarrow 100a - 100 = 100 \rightarrow a = \frac{200}{100} = 2
$$

Therefore:

$$
f(x) = 2x - 100
$$

This gives that $f(-273.15) = -646.3$.

Answer (score 1):

As you found, the size of an $N$ degree is $1/2$ a $C$ degree, so it takes twice as many $N$ degrees to be the same interval as $C$ degrees.  You missed the fact that $-100 N$ corresponds to $0 C$, so since absolute zero is $273.15$ below $0 C$, it is $2 \cdot 273.15$ below $-100 N$, which says absolute zero is $-100 -2 \cdot 273.15=-646.3 N$  Yes, that disagrees with your book.  It looks like the book used degrees F somehow-that gets close.

Comment: Using F as comparison scale doesn't change the answer. $$T_N = \dfrac{10}{9}*T_F -135.56$$ Absolute zero is -459.67 F which is then -646.3 N.