# "If $f$ is a linear function of the form $f(x)=mx+b$, then $f(u+v)=f(u)+f(v).$" True or false?

Tags: functions, proof-verification, examples-counterexamples

The rest of the question states the following: "If true, give an explanation as to why. If false, give a counter example."

Here is the following statement:

> If $f$ is a linear function of the form $f(x)=mx+b$, then $f(u+v)=f(u)+f(v).$

I know that this statement is false because I arbitrarily chose a function of the form $f(x)=mx+b$ and I plugged in random numbers for $u$ and $v$.

My actual question is this: is it sufficient enough to just use variables for counter-examples or must actual numbers be used?

Here is my work:

> False.
> Counter-example:
>
> Give $m$ and $b$ the values of $1/2$ and $3$, respectively. Therefore, $f(x)=mx+b$ becomes $f(x)=x/2+3$.
>
> Give $u$ and $v$ the values of $2$ and $4$, respectively. Now we have:
>
> $f(2)+f(4)=(1/2)(2)+3+(1/2)(4)+3=9.$
>
> $f(2+4)=f(6)=(1/2)(6)+3=6.$
>
> $9\neq6,$ so therefore, this statement is false.

Comment: Well, why bother plugging in values? You can see that $f(u)+f(v) = mu +mv + 2b$. Now you can actually find your answer if you set this equal to $f(u+v)$: namely, you'll find that $b$ must equal zero in order for equality to hold, and you're done. However, you are correct. All you need is to exhibit a single counterexample to show that the statement is false, so your method is completely correct.

Comment: Thanks! I remember that my teacher told me that plugging in variables is not sufficient for a counter example, although.

Comment: @Rellek Sorry. I only read your comment after  typing my answer. Should you decide to post it as an answer yourself and want me to delete mine, just let me know.

Comment: @Stefan Don't worry about it! I will keep it as a comment.

Comment: @C.Guan If you have a statement that asserts that a condition holds for ALL possible situations, then it is sufficient to provide a single counterexample to prove the statement false. However, if you are trying to prove that a statement is false in general, then a single counterexample is NOT sufficient.

Comment: Cool! Thanks a lot, @Rellek.

Comment: Thank you as well, @Stefan.

Comment: This is basically the [difference](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/275310/166367) between an affine function and a linear function.

Comment: I never thought about this that way @bjb568. Quite interesting.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, your counterexample suffices. However, there is an easier one:
Let $b \neq 0$. Then
$$
f(0 + 0 ) = b \neq 2b = f(0) + f(0),
$$

hence $f(u+v) = f(u) + f(v)$ does *not* hold for arbitrary $u,v$. On the other hand, if $b = 0$, it's easy to see that $f(u+v) = f(u) + f(v)$ for all $u,v$.