# Why is $y=f(a)+f'(a)(x-a)$ linear?

Tags: calculus, terminology, definition

I'm reading this book: [Functions of Several Variables](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=34Ic0K3LQxEC&printsec=frontcover&hl=pt-BR&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false) and I didn't understand why this function is linear:

[image]

I think the authors made a mistake.

Comment: Linear means degree 1. If 'a' is constant, then clearly it is.

Comment: This is linear with respect to $x$. Don't forget, $a$ is fixed! You can see that the slope of the line is $f'(a)$, and the y-intercept is $f(a)-af'(a)$, by expanding into the $y=mx+c$ form.

Comment: @Rishi Right! I was thinking about the linear algebra definition of "linear"

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг yes I know, I was thinking about the linear algebra definition of "linear"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the author meant "the *affine* function $y=f(a)+f'(a)(x-a)$" instead of "the *linear* function". Please have a look at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/275310/what-is-the-difference-between-linear-and-affine-function).

Comment: Certainly he did. Worth the point out.

Comment: It is common to refer to a function $f(x)=ax+b$ as linear, especially in high-school mathematics.

Comment: @Wojowu especially in calculus. I forgot that, shame on me.

Comment: ...Or a linear polynomial.