# Is $y = 2x + 1$ a linear system?

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider a system that is described by the linear equation: $y = 2x + 1$. Is this system linear or non-linear? From what I can tell, although the system is described by a linear equation is not linear, because the additivity property of the superposition principle does not stand.

Comment: See also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2054117/9464

Answer (score 2):

It's an inhomogenous linear equation. Maybe that helps you.

But you're right in the sense, that $x\mapsto2x+1$ is not a linear map.

Answer (score 0):

A linear system is of the form $A{\bf x}=b$ where $A$ is some matrix and $b$ is the known vector. The linearity is from $A$. Note that $y=2x+1$ is the same as $2x-y=-1$.