# Linear map and affine map definition coincides?

Tags: geometry

I'm reading through a geometry proof that claims that every affine map $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$ is the composition of a linear map and a translation. More precisely, $f$ is affine if and only if $f_0 =T_{-f(O)} \circ f$ is linear, where $T_{-f(O)}$ is the translation by the vector $-\overrightarrow{Of(O)}$.

One direction of the proof relies on showing that $f_0(\alpha A + \beta B)=\alpha f_0(A)+\beta f_0(B)$. However, how does this show that $f_0$ is linear? This is exactly what the definition of affine map is, so we've only shown that $f_0$ is affine, which isn't enough. I feel like we still need to show that $f_0$ transforms the origin into itself.

If anyone can recommend a good book on these topics I'd appreciate it, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

That’s the definition of a linear map, not an affine map. For example, consider the 1-D function

$$f(x)=mx+b$$

for some $m,b\in\mathbb{R}$ with $b\neq0$. This function is affine, but for $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$ and $\alpha,\beta\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $\alpha+\beta\neq1$, we have

$$f(\alpha x+\beta y)=m(\alpha x+\beta y)+b\neq \alpha f(x)+\beta f(y).$$

Comment: The way my teacher has defined affine maps is exactly when $\alpha + \beta = 1$. I think there's more confusion in my head than what I've asked about, I should read the definitions more carefully when I get the chance

Comment: @AstlyDichrar Getting the definitions straight is always a good idea. If you can show that a function satisfies the property for all $\alpha,\beta\in\mathbb{R}$, then it is linear. If you can show it for all $\alpha,\beta\in\mathbb{R}$ _such that_ $\alpha+\beta=1$, then it is affine.

Comment: Oh, maybe that is the part that I didn't notice. It's very possible that the proof didn't have the requirement that $\alpha +\beta = 1$.

Comment: @AstlyDichrar See [this old post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/275310) for some further discussion